# Negative dynamic index in Numba

Tags: python, numba

Numba seems to object to negative dynamic indices in tuples.

```
@jit
def test_fn():
    tup = (3,2,4,6,2)
    total = 0
    for idx in range(5):
        total += tup[-idx]
    return total
```

Gives `IndexError: tuple index out of range`, but is of course fine without the `@jit` decorator. Is this known / desired / inevitable behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

This definitely seems like a weird bug. If I use the `forceobj=True` argument to `numba.jit`, or if I pass in `locals` with any of the local variables `tup`, `total` or `idx` given an appropriate type, then the Numba functions works.

More puzzling, if I simply add calls to `numba.typeof(idx)`, then it also works, without needing extra arguments inside the call to `jit`. Unfortunately, when I run `numba --annotate` from the command line on my script with these modifications, it looks like all of them cause everything to be treated as `pyobject`.

This is all with numba 0.40.0.

Here are some of the changes I tried in a script:

```
# file 'test_numba.py'
import numba
import numpy as np

@numba.jit()
# @numba.jit(forceobj=True)
# @numba.jit(locals={'tup': tuple, 'idx': np.int64, 'total': np.int64})
#  also tried mixing and matching about 'locals' with and without the
#  numba.typeof calls below, and used `numba --annotate test_numba.py`
#  from command line to inspect annotated types.
def test_fn():
    tup = (3,2,4,6,2)
    total = 0
    print(numba.typeof(tup))
    print(numba.typeof(total))
    for idx in range(5):
        print(numba.typeof(idx))
        total += tup[-idx]
    return total

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_fn()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is weird indeed, compare to the code below, which works well:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def test_fn1():
    tup = (3, 2, 4, 6, 2)
    total = 0
    total += tup[-0]
    total += tup[-1]
    total += tup[-2]
    total += tup[-3]
    total += tup[-4]
return total
```

But your example doesn't (it breaks when idx is -1), seems like a bug to me.
I have this problem with both numba `0.39.0` and `0.40.0`.

Answer (score -2):

sorry, in my previous answer i was a bit confused.
this works:

```
@jit
def test_fn():
    tup = (3,2,4,6,2)
    total = 0
    for idx in tup: #changes have been made here
        total = total + idx #and here
    return total
```

old answer:

> the code is invalid:
>
> def test_fn():
>           tup = (3,2,4,6,2)
>           total = 0
>           for idx in range(5):
>               total += tup[-(idx+1)] #changes have been made here
>           return total
>   this happens because a index of '-0' is invalid. `list(range(5))` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` so -0 will happen. the fix makes it so '-0' will make '-1', because that is what returns what you want.
>
> EDIT: forgot to mention that a index of -0 actually gets accepted as 0, but that's invalid.

Comment: as a side note: a few years ago i struggled with this as well. it took me a few minutes of trial and error in the idle shell prompt to figure out.

Comment: What do you mean "that's invalid"? The code is fine in regular Python. As you say, the first element added is the zeroth. But it doesn't work in Numba. If you start the indexing at -1, it still doesn't.

Comment: Maybe it's not a good question, but I'm trying to make a point about negative indexing. I know how to write *this* example without using it, but sometimes it's convenient

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.